# How to transition from a page with an image to main/home page of a web site

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a page that has an image on it and that is it. After a couple of seconds without clicking on anything I want to transition to the site's home page where it has a top menu and all of the content of the site. I'm not sure how to do this. Is there any typescript involved? I am doing this using angular material/components.

**UPDATE** I posted my code example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajzq9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

You can see where it goes from the landing page to the first-page in 5 seconds but doesn't load the first-page. That's what I need assistance with.

I also don't know why my image doesn't show in the stackblitz example but it does in my localhost site but that is what the little missing square is when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that there're different ways to get what you want, but you can try this easy one:

In the ts code of your first page (page with the image), in its constructor ( or better, in the ngOninit() method), set a **timeout** or a delay with Vanilla Js, or even better, with some **RxJs observable operator** like *timeout* or *delay*. Then, inside its subscription, navigate to your page.

For instance, here it will navigate to the second page after 5 secs:

```
...
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
....

ngOnInit() {

of('Go!')
  .pipe(delay(5000))
  .subscribe((X) => {

    // Navigate to your desired page
    this.router.navigate(['path-to-page-after']);    // This should be the path of page that should open after the image page

  });

}
```

UPDATE :
My **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ampxro?file=src/app/app.component.html)** with your code working fine.
I hope it suits you!

Comment: Hi @Juan Vicente Berzosa Tejero. I tried this and it doesn't work. Maybe I have something wrong. I updated OP to show what I have so far.

Comment: I guess the problem is in the path: You don't have to put the name of the component (*'home-page.component.html'*), you have to use the **path's name of the component** that you have set in your routing (example *'/home'*). By the way, have you used **routing**?

Comment: Updated OP with app-routing.module code. I can see when it transitions after 5 seconds but the page it transitions to doesn't show. It still is stuck on the first page with the image.

Comment: Updated OP with stackblitz so you can see all of my code that I have. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: or anyone else with any help would be appreciated. I feel like I may be close just need some assistance. Thanks

Comment: ok, tomorrow I'll see your stackblitz (I actually just give it a quick glimpse rightnow, and I guess you only need to uncomment the router-outler...). I hopeI to remember tomorrow, because I'm a litlle bit busy.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a **stackbitz** with your code working as expected. I hope it suits you!